# Copy the value in sheet 1, and then use it to search on sheet 2

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a newbie on excel marcos, and am really interested in how to use it to improve efficiency. I got a question, which have been bothering me for a long time, and I can't find similar solution on google ... hope someone who had similar experience could help me to figure it out !

The question is, in sheet 1 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHPSy.png), I want to use each value in column B, and copy it to sheet 2 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoIiB.png) as a criteria of Auto-Filter on column A. If the value in column A of sheet 2 meet the criteria, then use the value of column A in sheet 1 as the criteria of column B in sheet 2, and if it meets the criteria, then copy the whole row in sheet 2 to sheet 3.

It's a bit complicate for me, as I have been searching on google for quite a long time ... really wish that someone can enlighten me on this ..

Many thanks in advance!!!
Jimmy

Comment: I am sorry but this site is for fixing  broken code. It is not a code writing service. If you make an attempt and get stuck post the code and we can help you out

Comment: Hi mate, below is what I wrote so far, I don't know how to copy the value that match in Sheet 2 to new sheet 3                                                 Sub Macro2_test()
'
' Macro2_test Macro


    For x = 2 To 3
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        po_number = Selection.Copy.Cells(x, 2).Value
        ActiveSheet.Sheets ("Sheet2")
        Sheet2.Range("$A$1:$AE$67803").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "=*po_number*", Operator:=xlAnd
        ActiveSheet.Sheets("Sheet3") = Sheet2.Copy
    Next
End Sub

Comment: Please put the code in the original post not in the comments using [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39898904/edit).

Answer (score 0):

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B").Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B")
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B:B").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlNo
```

and then compare critera, you could reference aswell

```
=IF(AND(B2>A2,B2<A3),"Yes","No")
```